# AppleScript to mount drive and, once finished, report if successful

Tags: applescript

I have written a script that mounts a drive before launching an application. The application, however, should only launch if the drive mounted successfully.

I have the correct code to mount the drive and launch the application, but I need to check if the mount was successful only after the operation has finished. At the moment it appears that the `if` statement is running immediately after the `mount`.

```
# Get wireless network SSID
set SSID to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk '/ SSID: / {print $2}'"

# Test if we are connected to the right network(s)
# We can test for multiple networks if you’re always on the move, like me!
# if SSID is "YOUR_SSID_ONE" or SSID is "YOUR_SSID_TWO" then
if SSID is "virginmedia7912273" or SSID is "virginmedia5097309" then
    tell application "Finder"
        # Mount your disk
        mount volume "afp://nas/iTunes/"
        # Check that the disk successfully mounted
        if exists disk "iTunes" then
            # If the disk successfully mounted, launch iTunes
            tell application "iTunes"
                # Launch launches, activate brings window to focus (?)
                launch
                activate
            end tell
        else
            # If the disk didn’t mount, throw an error.
            display dialog "Unable to connect to iTunes storage device."
        end if
    end tell
else
    # If we are not connected to the right network(s), throw an error.
    display dialog "You are not connected to your home network."
end if
```

Comment: Did you try inserting a delay after the mount command?

Comment: Is that the best way to do it? Wondered if I could get the script to block somehow? I don't know AppleScript very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the mount was successful with a cycle like this:

```
repeat until name of every disk contains "iTunes"
   delay 1
end repeat
```

You could also add a condition to exit the loop after a certain number of iterations:

```
set i to 0
repeat until (name of every disk contains "iTunes" or i is greater than max_number_of_iteration)
   delay 1
   set i to i + 1
end repeat
```

**EDIT:**

The script must be modified to be compatible with latest macOS versions:

```
tell application "System Events" to set diskNames to name of every disk 
set i to 0
set max_number_of_iteration to 5
repeat until (diskNames contains "iTunes" or i is greater than max_number_of_iteration)
    tell application "System Events" to set diskNames to name of every disk 
    delay 1
    set i to i + 1
end repeat
```

Thanks to [a walker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7711430/a-walker) for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm trying out the second example you gave, but I'm getting this error: `Syntax Error: Expected “from”, etc. but found “not”.` http://cl.ly/image/1h0L2s223j1w/content

Comment: I changed it to this and it worked: `repeat until (name of every disk contains diskName or i is greater than 10)`

Comment: You are right, I inverted the conditions and also made a sintax error. The scripts are now fixed.

Comment: At this moment (almost 4 years later) I get an Syntax Error "Expected class name but found identifier." Anybody know what can cause and solve this?